# Is there ever a case in SQL where a subquery is more efficient than a join?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I've seen people hypothetically say that there are cases when a subquery can be more efficient than a join but I have never actually seen a good example of this?

What would be a case when you would want to use a subquery over a join?

Comment: Doubt there is ever a hard rule of one always being faster, especially given one relation database may be better or worse at some things than others.  I would test both ways out if you need the absolute fastest solution for a given problem in your environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic example is searching for rows in a table that do not have corresponding rows in another.

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM TableB b WHERE b.parent_id = a.id)
```

is generally better than

```
SELECT a.* 
    FROM TableA a
        LEFT JOIN TableB b
            ON a.id = b.parent_id
    WHERE b.parent_id IS NULL
```

See also: [Left outer join vs NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)

Comment: +1 Depends on implementation though. I think in MySQL for example subquery performance is pretty bad generally.

Answer (score 2):

When using EXISTS with a sub-query the sub-query solution should be faster (compared to an outer join and checking for NULL), because the "evaluation" of the sub-query terminates as soon as the first row is returned.

My experience is that most of the time the query optimizer chooses the same plan anyway, so that there is no performance difference between both of them (at least with Oracle and PostgreSQL)

Comment: Are you talking about `not exists`?

Comment: @Martin: I do mean `exists` - compared to `IS NOT NULL` in an outer join.

Comment: That isn't semantically the same then is it? `EXISTS` won't return duplicates if the sub query has multiple joining rows.

Comment: @Martin: you are right. But depending on what you want to get, it might be an alternative